# Jpa EntityManager not persist data with creation by EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

In my application written in playframework 2.3.X I created an EntityManager (wanting to avoid to use persistence.xml) through the EntityManagerFactory interface. So all the reading database operations are carried out correctly, but when I call the persist method on the object in question the data is not saved.

Below the class to generate the EntityManager:

```
public final class PersistenceManager extends Controller {
    

    @Transactional
    @PersistenceContext
    private static EntityManager getEM(CustomDB customDB) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = createEMFactory("jdbc:mysql://" + customDB.getDatabaseUrl() + ":" + customDB.getDatabasePort() + "/"+ customDB.getDatabaseName() + "?useSSL=true", customDB.getDatabaseUser(), customDB.getDatabasePassword());
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return em;

    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory createEMFactory(String dbUrl, String dbUser, String dbPassword) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        props.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection","class");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql","false");
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql","true");
        props.put("hbm2ddl.auto","create");

        props.put("hibernate.connection.url", dbUrl);
        props.put("hibernate.connection.username", dbUser);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(dbPassword)) {
            props.put("hibernate.connection.password", dbPassword);
        }

        PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = new PersistenceUnitInfo() {

            @Override
            public Properties getProperties() {
                return props;
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
                return Arrays.asList(
                        Address.class.getName(),
                        City.class.getName(),
                        User.class.getName()
                );
            }

            @Override
            public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
                return "Test";
            }

            @Override
            public String getPersistenceProviderClassName() {
                return HibernatePersistenceProvider.class.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
                return PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;
            }

            @Override
            public DataSource getJtaDataSource() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public DataSource getNonJtaDataSource() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            @Override
            public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
                try {
                    return Collections.list(this.getClass()
                            .getClassLoader()
                            .getResources(""));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean excludeUnlistedClasses() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void addTransformer(ClassTransformer transformer) {

            }

            @Override
            public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        HibernatePersistenceProvider hibernatePersistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();

        return hibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitInfo, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);


    }
}
```

This is my controller class to interact with the User entity:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {
    
    @Transactional
    public Result writeUser(CustomDB customDB ){
        EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getEM(customDB);
        List<User> userList = em.createNamedQuery("userByName").setParameter("name","Jane").getResultList();                                             
        User user = userList.get(0);
        user.phoneNumber("0123456789");
        em.persist(user);
    } 
}
```

The query "userByName", or in any case any type of read operation, takes the data, but the persist operation does not write into database. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I assume that there is no transaction assosciate with entity manager. So no commit will happen. Please read the docs https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaJPA

Comment: There is no transaction and I follow the doc: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA